# Upload, edit and then download the edited image in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm uploading an image, applying css filters to it. My goal is to download the edited image. But I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

I want to know how I could download the edited image. Currently I'm just downloading the original uploaded image in the `handleDownload()`.

The image uploaded is set to background-image of a div. I'm applying CSS filters on the image.

I'm new to React so forgive my code quality.

```
const App = () => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
  const [selectedOptionIndex, setSelectedOptionIndex] = useState(0);
  const [isImagePresent, setIsImagePresent] = useState(false);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const imageRef = useRef(null);

  function handleSliderChange(e) {
    setOptions((previousOptions) => {
      return previousOptions.map((option, index) => {
        if (index === selectedOptionIndex)
          return { ...option, value: e.target.value };
        return option;
      });
    });
    updateImageStyle();
  }

  function updateImageStyle() {
    const filters = options.map((option) => {
      return `${option.property}(${option.value}${option.unit})`;
    });

    if (imageRef.current) {
      imageRef.current.style.filter = filters.join(" ");
    }
  }

  function handleUpload(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      setImage(file);
      setIsImagePresent(true);
      if (imageRef.current) {
        imageRef.current.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageUrl})`;
      }
    }
  }

  function handleDownload() {
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    console.log(image);
    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(image);
    downloadLink.download = image.name;
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  }

  function resetFilters() {
    setOptions(DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    updateImageStyle();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="main-image" ref={imageRef} />
        <div className="sidebar">
          {options.map((option, index) => {
            return (
              <SidebarItem
                key={index}
                name={option.name}
                active={index === selectedOptionIndex}
                handleClick={() => {
                  setSelectedOptionIndex(index);
                  if (imageRef.current && isImagePresent) {
                    updateImageStyle();
                  }
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
          <div className="btn-container">
            <button className="action-btn">Upload</button>
            <button
              className="action-btn"
              disabled={!isImagePresent}
              onClick={handleDownload}
            >
              Download
            </button>
            <button className="action-btn" onClick={resetFilters}>
              Reset
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        {isImagePresent && (
          <Slider
            min={options[selectedOptionIndex].range.min}
            max={options[selectedOptionIndex].range.max}
            value={options[selectedOptionIndex].value}
            handleChange={handleSliderChange}
          />
        )}
      </div>

      {!isImagePresent && <UploadOption handleUpload={handleUpload} />}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: CSS filters are applied on top of the image when rendering the page, they don't modify the image itself. Perhaps you would be better off looking into using an HTML canvas for modifying the image.

Comment: my plan was to create an image whenever download button was hit and apply all the filters to the image. But I don't know how this can be achieved. I've tried canvas but there's always some error.